# How to loop in the list and apply an Arithmetic operation of different keys elements and calculate the final value using Java 8 and Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, java-stream

I have **class** `DTO` which have 4 fields.

And I have a list of `DTO` objects.

I want to do an **arithmetic operation** with **values** of the elements with the *same* **dataPeriod**. As a final result I need to generate computed result and create new `DTO`, see the below example. How to apply formula using **Java 8** and **Stream**

```
@lombok.Data
@AllArgsConstructor
static class DTO {
    String key;
    int dataPeriod;
    int year;
    Double value;
}
```

Below list i have orderBy dataPeriod that is why is look like this so that my formula works correctly.

```
list.add(new DTO("A", 1, 2020, 5.0));
list.add(new DTO("B", 1, 2020, -9.0));

list.add(new DTO("A", 2, 2020, 8.0));
list.add(new DTO("B", 2, 2020, 3.5));

list.add(new DTO("A", 3, 2020, 1.5));
list.add(new DTO("B", 3, 2020, 7.0));

list.add(new DTO("A", 4, 2020, -6.0));
list.add(new DTO("B", 4, 2020, 5.0));

list.add(new DTO("A", 5, 2020, 1.5));
list.add(new DTO("B", 5, 2020, -7.0));
```

I want to apply the below **formula** for by loop in all the **dataPeriod** like below we have 5:

I have done using normal java code but how to do the same using **java 8** and **Stream** may be here we can use **Recursive function** but how? Any one can please help me for this.
Thanks in advance!!

**NOTE:**- Into the formula A always come first in the list otherwise wrong result will be given.

> ****C** = **C** - (**A[i]** - **B[i]**)**    [where **i** is dataPeriod and initial value of **C** is **ZERO**]

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double C = 0.0;
       for (int i = 0; i < list.size() / 2; i++) {
           C = C - (list.get(i * 2).getValue() - list.get(i * 2 + 1).getValue());
       }

    System.out.println(new DTO("C", 0, 2020, C));
 }
```

***Expected OP: ***

```
Test.DTO(key=C, dataPeriod=0, year=2020, value=-10.5)
```

Comment: Your formula says `C - (A[i] * B[i])`, but your code is doing `C - (A[i] - B[i])`. Also, your text says it's `dataPeriod` that's used, but the code pulls `getValue()`. Which is it?

Comment: Thanks. And the second part is about the field?

Comment: @ernest_k I want to apply formula for same dataPeriod for different key in the value.

Comment: You don't need streams here, just keep it.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Thanks your comment but I know this possible in using java 8 and stream also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IntStream` to iterate the indexes of the `list` and then reduce with `d1, d2) -> d1 - d2` using `0` as identity:

```
double c = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)
        .limit(list.size() / 2)
        .mapToDouble(i -> list.get(i).getValue() - list.get(i + 1).getValue())
        .reduce(0d, (d1, d2) -> d1 - d2);

DTO dto = new DTO("C", 0, 2020, c);
```

Alternatively, you can `stream` the `list` and collect using `Collectors.groupingBy` with `DTO::getDataPeriod` classifier, and mapping values using `DTO::getValue`.

Then you can `stream` the values of the resulting `Map<Integer, Double>`, convert the `stream` to `DoubleStream`, and reduce using `sum()`.

```
double c = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DTO::getDataPeriod, 
        Collectors.mapping(DTO::getValue, 
                Collectors.reducing(0d, (v1, v2) -> v2 - v1))))
        .values().stream()
        .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
        .sum();

DTO dto = new DTO("C", 0, 2020, c);
```

Comment: Thanks @Oboe what changes required in case my values in BIgDecimal? Actually i made the test scenarios from my actual code.

Comment: Because MaptoBigDecimal fuction not in java

Comment: @Rishi Kumar Yes, in the case of the `IntStream`, instead of  `mapToDouble` you would have to map using `mapToObj` with `list.get(i).getValue().subtract(list.get(i + 1).getValue())`. Then reduce with `.reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (d1, d2) -> d1 .subtract(d2))`.  In the second case you would have to replace `Collectors.reducing(0d, (v1, v2) -> v2 - v1))` with `Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, (v1, v2) -> v2 .subtract(v1))`, and replace `sum()` with `reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (v1, v2) -> v1 .subtract(v2))`.